# Compiling my custom keymap using QMK MSYS returns a multiple target patterns error

Tags: keyboard, msys, keymapping, qmk, qmk-firmware

I am following the steps outlined [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CilhJ.jpg) to customize my [Planck OLKB](https://switchandclick.com/drop-olkb-planck-review/) rev6 keyboard. I'm using **QMK MSYS** to perform all the command line level stuff.

I followed all the steps and everything works fine up until I need to compile the keyboard and a custom keymap using the **qmk compile** command. I keep getting an error:

**Makefile:507: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.**

The issue is also present when I try to compile the default Planck keymap. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there any additional setup that is required.

I tried compiling using the JSON keymap file obtained from QMK configurator directly and that works (`qmk compile [-c] <configuratorExport.json>`).

Comment: No solution. This was abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

For those struggling with compiling QMK locally, consider using Docker to compile it. You can run `util/docker_build.sh <keyboard>:<keymap>`

Docs: https://docs.qmk.fm/#/getting_started_docker

Of course this requires a local Docker installation, but that's arguably easier than installing all the build tools.